# Error: fatal error call to a member function execute() on boolean on line 30

Tags: php, mysql

fatal error call to a member function execute() on boolean on line 30. The pages loads up but it just gives me one error I have no idea why its giving me the error.

This code is connected to a webpage but it won't load up my product page because of this one error.

```
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="products.php">Your Site</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <?php echo $page_title=="Products" ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> >
                    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li <?php echo $page_title=="Cart" ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> >
                    <a href="cart.php">
                        <?php
                        // query to count all product in cart
                        $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM cart_items WHERE user=1";

                        // prepare query statement
                        $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );

                        // execute query error is here
                        $stmt->execute();

                        // get row value
                        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                        // return count
                        $cart_count=$rows[0];
                        ?>
                        Cart <span class="badge" id="comparison-count"><?php echo $cart_count; ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: `$con->prepare` fails, so `$stmt` is false. Where is the db connection?

Comment: It's in a database.php file

Comment: And you include it in this file? It succeeds?

Comment: No I didn't include it in this file. Should I upload that file too.

Comment: Yup. Use [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) for that.

Comment: Where should I add require_once

Comment: At top of your file. Anyway, before any database interaction.

Comment: Ok so do that for the database.php file right